# WHERE IN with a local variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, where-clause, where-in

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)
>   [SQL:Casting a String to IDS with IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773539/sqlcasting-a-string-to-ids-with-in-clause)

I want to use a declare local variable in a `WHERE IN` clause

Something like this:

**TABLE XYZ**

```
COL1 COL2
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    D
5    E
```

RESULT

```
1 A
2 B
5 E
```

QUERY

```
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @VAR = '1,2,5'
SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE COL1 IN @VAR
```

How do I do this?

Note :
I cant have a server function

I can only create primitive value (by code) and use it with my query.
I search a way that I will only change my var and not the query itself.

my code look like:

```
list (dbparameter)
mylist.add ('@var','1,2,5')

commandsql.returnresult(myQueryInString,mylist)
```

I want to

Comment: tank you bluefeet, I still have issue with forum template

Comment: I cant create a function in the database

Answer (score 5):

```
DECLARE @var TABLE
        (
        value INT
        )

INSERT
INTO    @var
VALUES
        (1), (3), (5)

/* You would need three separate inserts in 2005 */

SELECT  *
FROM    xyz
WHERE   col1 IN
        (
        SELECT  value
        FROM    @var
        )
```

You can also write a table-valued function which splits a `CSV`, but if your client library supports passing table variables, this is a preferred option.

You can find the function definition in the [Erlang Sommarskog's article](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#CSV) (search for `simple_intlist_to_tbl`). Declare it and call like this:

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(100) = '1,3,5'

SELECT  *
FROM    xyz
WHERE   col1 IN
        (
        SELECT  number
        FROM    simple_intlist_to_tbl(@var)
        )
```

If your query is more complex than that, you would want to materialize this list first:

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(100) = '1,3,5'

DECLARE @tvar TABLE
        ( 
        number INT
        )

INSERT
INTO    @tvar
SELECT  number
FROM    simple_intlist_to_tbl(@var)

SELECT  *
FROM    xyz, ... /* Other complex joins */
WHERE   col1 IN
        (
        SELECT  number
        FROM    @tvar
        )
```

Comment: and the var should be set in code, and I just have primitif type. So I will not able to push X number of value in @var.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function which splits your list into a data set ([use this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) from Jeff Moden it works and is very fast) and then just use the IN clause on your desired column(s).

Comment: I CANT create a function on the server

Comment: You can run the code in-line within your query it will work just the same. Scroll to the very bottom of the article if you don't want to read through all of it.